# Setting a WorkbenchWindowControlContribution as a SelectionProvider

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I added a control in the toolbar which extends `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution` and implements  `ISelectionProvider`. This control contains a Combo and when I change the selection I want to notify another view. Because it's not a ViewPart I can't call `getSite().setSelectionProvider` directly. I tried to set it like this:

```
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(() -> {
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart().getSite().setSelectionProvider(MyControl.this);
    });
```

If I add this to the `protected Control createControl(Composite parent)` method the getActivePart would always be null. I also tried registering it when the Combo's value changes for the first time, but that way my other View wasn't notified about the change event.

Here is the ISelectionProvider methods:

```
@Override
public void addSelectionChangedListener(ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
}

@Override
public ISelection getSelection() {
    return new StructuredSelection(comboBox.getText());
}

@Override
public void removeSelectionChangedListener(ISelectionChangedListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
}

@Override
public void setSelection(ISelection selection) {
    for (ISelectionChangedListener listener : listeners) {
        listener.selectionChanged(new SelectionChangedEvent(this, selection));
    }

}
```

The View that should be getting notified implements `ISelectionListener`. I register it in the `public void createPartControl(Composite parent)` with `getSite().getPage().addSelectionListener(this);`

And here is the override of the SelectionChanged too:

```
@Override
public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
    if (part instanceof MyControl) {
        String selectedProtocol = ((StructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement().toString();           
    }
}
```

Can it be done?
Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to give the selection to a specific view it would be simpler just to use IWorkbenchPage.findView and call a method on the view. I don't see anything doing anything like this in the Eclipse source.